# Yet another Android SQLite database question

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to create two tables in DB, how do I do it using SQLiteOpenHelper descendant and overriding onCreate metod? Will the below code be ok? Seems I'm doing it wrong.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
      db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+CATEGORY_TABLE+" ("+_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
              CATEGORY_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL);");    

      db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+RECIPES_TABLE+" ("+_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
              RECIPE_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+CATEGORY_ID+" INTEGER, "+ RECIPE+" TEXT NOT NULL);");
  }
```

Comment: I used GUI programm to explore my DB and found only 1 table there :\

Comment: If you added second statement after you run your app at least once - you'll need to uninstall/or clear data.

Answer (score 0):

In fact all the creation statements must be executed inside one execSQL statement. Another point that if your want to change your db schema you must increase the db version - then onCreate will be called again.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I would suggest "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" instead of just "CREATE TABLE" that even if the same SQL statement is executed twice you don't get the exception.